# Наиболее правильная реализация сайта

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, анимация

Надо сделать сайт по макету (см. гифку) на `React`. Как правильнее будет реализовать переходы и разные окна что там фигурируют? Просто ли это будут кастомные элементы или лучше это сделать как-то по другому?

[image: Макет]

Comment: Ну тут есть два варианта. Либо сделать отдельными компонентами, переключать их видимость и хранить состояние в родителе. Либо сделать отдельными роутами и хранить состояние в редаксе например

Comment: @RavenTheX а как было бы правильне, возможно, в долгосрочной перспективе?

Comment: Если нужно менять урл, однозначно второй вариант

Comment: @RavenTheX если в будущем, если нейронная сеть создана, надо будет перебрасывать сразу на третий слайд, пропуская первые два, правильней ли делать это сразу отдельными роутами?